# IOS/Objective-C: Core Data NSPredicate using IN not returning all matches

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am trying to use an `NSPredicate` during a fetch from core data to filter results as part of a serversync.

My `NSPredicate` is as follows:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"iid IN %@", uids];
```

By doing a fetch of all the managed objects first, I have ascertained that there are about 6000 of them in the store, all with iids.  There are about 10 uids 
so that the predicate logs to console as:

```
iid IN {"9037", "9036", "8953", "9023", "9034", "9029", "9028", "9024", "8959", "8957"}
```

From logging out all the iids, I have verified that all the uids are matched.  However, when I do the fetch, I am  getting only three or four matches back instead of 10. The number varies.

I suspect the issue is with threading and context, as I start out using a private context to bring down the uids from server as suggested by Apple. To find out what's in the local store, I have used the main context. It is this fetch to the main context that is not acting properly, however, I don't know how to fix it.

Thanks for any suggestions on how to solve this.

Code for sync:

```
   NSManagedObjectContext *mainMOC = self.managedObjectContext;
         NSManagedObjectContext*private =[[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
         [private setParentContext:mainMOC];
         [private performBlock:^{
             myItems = [self convertFeedtoObject:latestItems];
             [self importAndSaveItems:myItems inContext:private];
             NSError *error = nil;
             if (![self.private save:&error]) {
                 NSLog(@"Error saving context: %@\n%@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
                 abort();
             }
             [mainMOC performBlockAndWait:^{
                 NSError *error = nil;
                 if (![mainMOC save:&error]) {

                 }
                 else {
                     _managedObjectContext = mainMOC;
                 }
             }];
         }];
         mainMOC=nil;
```

//Code for fetch called from importAndSaveItems

```
-(id) getExistingItems:(NSArray *)uids
{

  NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Items"];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [Model sharedInstance].managedObjectContext;
     NSError *error      = nil;
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"iid IN %@", uids];

    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate;

         NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Items" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    fetchRequest.entity = entity;

    NSArray *results    = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                                   error:&error];
 return results;
}
```

Comment: Do not use the main context to fetch `getExistingItems`, use the `private` context there as well, you are breaking the main rule of using main managed context off the main thread...since you are calling it from the private context's queue (inside of `performBlock`)

Comment: That seems to have fixed it.  Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I will post it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the main context to fetch `getExistingItems`, use the private context there as well, you are breaking the main rule of using main managed context off the main thread...since you are calling it from the private context's queue (inside of `performBlock`)